# Harsanyi purification for games with infinite action space?

Tags: game-theory

Harsanyi's purification (1973; see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purification_theorem)) seems to apply only to games with finite action space.

Is there also a similar result for games with infinite action space (e.g., players choosing prices) ?